# Show a div when click on related link and hide the others

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, click, show

I've this code:

```
<head>
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
        // Optional code to hide all divs
        $("div").hide();
          // Show chosen div, and hide all others
        $("a").click(function () 
        {
            $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
        });

    });

</script>

</head>

<body>
    Click a button to make it visible:<br /><br />
<a href="" class="one">One</a>
<a href="" class="two">Two</a>
<a href="" class="three">Three</a>
<a href="" class="four">Four</a><br /><br />

    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
    <div id="three">Three</div>
    <div id="four">Four</div><br/><br/>




</body>
```

I want to display a div when the related link is clicked. The problem is that this process lasts only few seconds. Someone knows why? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
        $("a").click(function (e) 
    {
            e.preventDefault();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
    });
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsmVn/)

Answer (score 2):

You should specify # in the `href`:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

Here is the **demo**: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXE9p/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add common class to all divs like

```
<div id="one" class="div">One</div>
<div id="two" class="div">Two</div>
<div id="three" class="div">Three</div>
<div id="four" class="div">Four</div>
```

js:

```
$("a").click(function (){         
    $(".div").hide();            
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
});
```