# Open a popup window (which contains text) HTML link

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, popup, http-status-code-404

Here is the structure of my link:

```
<a href="My texte" title="Ouverture d'une nouvelle fenêtre popup"
     onclick="window.open(this.href,'nom_Popup','​height=400 , width=400 ,location=no ,resizable=yes ,scrollbars=yes');return false;">+</a></div>
```

when I click on the +, I have a pop up that contains:

```
HTTP Status 404 -
```

how do I it contains what I want as text

Answer (score 4):

Put  the content in another `html` page and specify it's path in the `<a>`s `href` attribute...
like

```
<a href="index.html" title="Ouverture d'une nouvelle fenêtre popup"
 onclick="window.open(this.href,'nom_Popup','​height=400 , width=400 ,location=no ,resizable=yes ,scrollbars=yes');return false;">+</a></div>
```

Comment: but the content of my index.html is not static. 
details: I have a group of artists, when I click on the link, I want to have a pop up of his biography, therefore, the contents of my pop up is not static, but change depending on the artist. 

My problem: have a pop up that custom text

Comment: Anyway you'll need to have that content in `html` somewhere so that you can display it... with your approach you'll need one html page per artist... which IMHO is not the way to do it. create several hidden divs with each artists information, on clicking the respective hyperlink simply show them. just search stack overflow 'how to hide and show divs' and you'll be overwhelmed with answers..

Comment: is that it is possible to display a div right next to the link when I click on?

Comment: @FRIDIMourad well of course yes.. there are already thousands of answers on how to do it,  please do some research on how to do it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843244/show-a-div-when-click-on-related-link-and-hide-the-others

Answer (score 0):

this.href means the href tag of the anchor you're clicking on. You need to specify the link you want to open in the new window.

Comment: I want when I click the link, a short description (which is not fixed, it changes every time) is displayed in a pop up, my text is not known in advance

Comment: Are you using any server side language like php? or the content is static html files but the blocks of text are different?
What you can do is you can pass the artist name in the href like index.html?artist=123 so in the index.html page you can put up javascript check for that artist parameter you passed. based on that you can show the relevant content.