# Jquery show hide div when click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show-hide

I am trying to show hide div blocks depending on the link on which it click. By default all div will hide. All helps are appreciated.

**HTML Code -**

```
<div class="singleFlights">
   <div class="itinerarySummary">
     <div class="itineraryMenu">
         <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="#flight-itinery">Flight itinerary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fare-rules">Fare rules</a></li>
            <li><a href="#baggage-info">Baggage Information</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="itineraryPanel">
         <div id="flight-itinery" class="itineraryPanelItem">
            <!-- Content Here -->
         </div>
         <div id="fare-rules" class="itineraryPanelItem">
            <!-- Content Here -->
         </div>
         <div id="baggage-info" class="itineraryPanelItem">
            <!-- Content Here -->
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="singleFlights">
.....................
.....................
</div>
```

**Requirements -**

By default 'itineraryPanel' div hide. 
If user click on '**Flight itinerary**' link under '**itineraryMenu**' the div '**itineraryPanel**' will show (slide down)with '**itineraryPanelItem**' item div. Others div '#**fare-rules**' and '#**baggage-info**' will hide. Same will be happen when click on **Fare rules** and **Baggage Information** also.

I try with -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.flightListing').length > 0){
        $('.singleFlights').each(function(){
            $('.itineraryMenu ul.list-inline li a').click(function(){

            });
        });
    }
});
```

I am using bootstrap3. Note that I dont want to show 'itineraryPanel' div until user not click of any link. and after click 2nd time on same link open div slide up and hide.

Here is the live code after included of **Vincent G** codes - http://45.114.142.104/design//test/cloud/flight-listing-1-n.html

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a div when click on related link and hide the others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843244/show-a-div-when-click-on-related-link-and-hide-the-others)

Comment: Did you search at all for a solution before asking? https://www.google.com/search?q=show%2Fhide+a+div+when+I+click+a+link+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=show%2Fhide+a+div+when+I+click+a+link+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=serp.3...48199.52150.0.52244.25.25.0.0.0.0.116.2063.22j3.25.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.3.251.lHoR62yiemQ

Comment: not duplicate post here is the different @ TylerH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with jQuery and `data-href` elements

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szmoqao3/4/)

```
$(function(){
    $(".list-inline a").click(function(){
        hrefId = $(this).data('href');
    $('.itineraryPanelItem').slideUp();
        if($(hrefId).is(':visible')){
        $(hrefId).slideUp();
    }else{
      $('.itineraryPanel').show();
        $(hrefId).slideDown();
    }    
  });
});
```

**EDIT**
With multiples content, you have to use `class` instead of `id`

[See this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szmoqao3/5/)

```
$(function(){
    $(".list-inline a").click(function(){
        hrefClass = $(this).data('href');
    $(this).parents('.singleFlights').find('.itineraryPanelItem').slideUp();
        if($(this).parents('.singleFlights').find($(hrefClass)).is(':visible')){
        $(this).parents('.singleFlights').find(hrefClass).slideUp();
    }else{
      $(this).parents('.singleFlights').find('.itineraryPanel').show();
        $(this).parents('.singleFlights').find(hrefClass).slideDown();
    }    
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent G but not like that.

Comment: see an example, click on any flight itineary or fare rule after hover -http://www.cleartrip.com/flights/results?from=CCU&to=BOM&depart_date=26/05/2016&adults=1&childs=0&infants=0&class=Economy&airline=&carrier=&intl=n&sd=1459541681089&page=loaded

Comment: I have update your code. Live - http://45.114.142.104/design//test/cloud/flight-listing-1-n.html

Comment: I dont want to show 'itineraryPanel' div until user not click of any link. and after click 2nd time on same link open div slide up and hide.

Comment: All right, I've edited my code with your precisions. Do you understand it ?

Comment: Thank you Vincent. I have upload code on live.But It's not working properly also it's not work for others flight rows. Please help me to fix. Update file at - http://45.114.142.104/design//test/cloud/flight-listing-1-n.html

Comment: Script file name flightScriptV2.js, added it on end of the page.

Comment: Hello Vincent its not work when added multipule flight row (singleFlights). Please help me.

Comment: Of course it's not working, you have multiples IDs which are the same and that is not correct. 
You have to use class instead

Comment: Your code is working fine as per my post. But need to solve for multiples IDs. How to solve this? Please help me. Did you see the live url ?@Vincent

Comment: I've edited my answer and use class like I said. But are you sure to understand the code I did ?